# rails app shows access denied in webbrowser

Tags: mysql

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I setup a new environment where mysql does not have a password and how I am getting this error.  Where do I change

```
'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

my database.yml is show below my database is sample_app

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/development.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sample_app
  username: root
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/test.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sample_app
  username: root
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

 production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/production.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sample_app
  username: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: You might be interested in this related problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/56120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using root to connect to a db with an app.  Create a new user/password with a name to recognize that it is being used for a specific app\task then use that instead of root.

add this for empty password `password:`

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/production.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sample_app
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

If you still get access denied, then the db is saying that the user\password is not valid

Answer (score 1):

If this,

```
 $ mysql -u root
```

takes you to mysql then this will work,

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/production.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sample_app
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

If you have set some password to your root user, then try

```
$ mysql -u root -p
<<It will prompt for a password, key it in>>
```

If that takes you to mysql then this will work,

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/production.mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sample_app
  username: root
  password: <<password>>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Moral of the story:**

*First, try logging into mysql using mysql command from command-line and see if it works.
Then, use those credentials in database.yml and log into mysql from rails application.*